# Calling JQuery function onload and onclick

Tags: jquery

I have a RadionButtonList with two values and on click I gotta hide some elements on my page.

I got the following code that triggers on click on a RadionButton. How do I call this on the Page load of my page?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%= columnsRoundPanel.FindControl("rdlClickOrder").ClientID %> input').click(function () {
    var clickOrder = $(this).val();
    $('#<%= chkColumnList.ClientID %> input').each(function (i) {
      var index = ($(this).next('label').text().indexOf(clickOrder));

      if ((index == -1) && ($(this).next('label').text() != 'Cost' && $(this).next('label').text() != 'Clicks' && $(this).next('label').text() != 'Impressions')) {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'none');
      } else {
        $(this).css('display', 'inline');
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'inline');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is a RadionButtonList? jQuery has no such concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the `click` event right after you've registered your handler:

```
$('#<%= columnsRoundPanel.FindControl("rdlClickOrder").ClientID %> input')
    .click(function() {
        // Your handler...
    }).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#<%= columnsRoundPanel.FindControl("rdlClickOrder").ClientID %> input').click();
```

after your code

Comment: Or just replace the trailing `}); });` with `}).click(); });`.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: yes, it's possible, too. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%= columnsRoundPanel.FindControl("rdlClickOrder").ClientID %> input').click(function () {
    var clickOrder = $(this).val();
    $('#<%= chkColumnList.ClientID %> input').each(function (i) {
      var index = ($(this).next('label').text().indexOf(clickOrder));

      if ((index == -1) && ($(this).next('label').text() != 'Cost' && $(this).next('label').text() != 'Clicks' && $(this).next('label').text() != 'Impressions')) {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'none');
      } else {
        $(this).css('display', 'inline');
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'inline');
      }
    });
  }).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just call the `click` method after you have attached the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#<%= columnsRoundPanel.FindControl("rdlClickOrder").ClientID %> input').click(function () {
    var clickOrder = $(this).val();
    $('#<%= chkColumnList.ClientID %> input').each(function (i) {
      var index = ($(this).next('label').text().indexOf(clickOrder));

      if ((index == -1) && ($(this).next('label').text() != 'Cost' && $(this).next('label').text() != 'Clicks' && $(this).next('label').text() != 'Impressions')) {
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'none');
      } else {
        $(this).css('display', 'inline');
        $(this).next('label').css('display', 'inline');
      }
    });
  }).click();
});
```